# php - can't retain session values when navigating to another page

Tags: php, html, session

I'm developing a php application and i have a problem retaining session values. I have two files, one is a sidebar (sidebar.php) and a home page (home.php). I have included the sidebar on the home page. 
There are login controls on the sidebar and i can successfully login. I know it has successfully logged in because it shows me a message Welcome 'username'. But when i go to the home page, the welcome 'username' part is not shown as the session values are destroyed. instead the login form is shown. Why is that?

This is the home page (sidebar.php)

```
<?php require_once('connections.php'); ?>
<?php
// if the login button is clicked
if (isset($_POST['btnLogin']))
{


$myusername=$_POST['textusername'];
$mypassword=$_POST['textpassword'];

$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users_table WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'");

$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

if($count>=1)
{

$_SESSION['username'] = $row["username"] ;
$_SESSION['userid']= $row["ID"];

}
else 
{ 

//Any code here

}

}
?>

<div class="col-md-12 right-aside">  

<?php


if (isset($_SESSION['userid']))
{
echo Welcome : " .  $_SESSION['username'];
echo "  <a href='logout.php'> | Logout</a>";
}

else //if session is not set
{

echo 'Some html for login form';

}

?>
</div>
```

The following is the home page (home.php)

```
<?php include("head.php"); ?> 
<body>
<div class="container container-body">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-9 main-content">
             <div class="row">                               

               <p>Some Text Here</p>

             </div><!-- /.row -->
          </div><!-- /.main-content -->
        <div class="col-md-3">

  <div class="row">
      <?php include 'sidebar.php';?>      
  </div>

 </div>
```

Comment: before putting value in session start the session if it has not been already started and put the value in session.

Comment: when i do that it shows the following error.

I did, but that throws an error on the side bar.
Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\trialphp\head.php:38)

head.php is basically the css and script files and i have imported that on the home.php. it only contans some <head>Some css and some scripts</head>

Comment: Don't get used to work with plain text passwords,.. first think you should manage is strong hashing/encryption (not md5, not even with salt). `mysql_` deprecated, no string escaping, no `session_start()`?

Comment: i omitted a lot of code, code which isn't relevant to my problem such as queries and encryption. But i would like to know more about the encryption, what i've actually used is 

$mypassword=$_POST['textboxPassword'];

$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);

$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);

$mypassword = md5($mypassword);

If there is anything i can do to make it better, i'm all ears :)

Comment: @Enq, the correct way of handling passwords would be, (in short), when an user registers, hash the password using `sha1($password)` , and then insert it into your database. Then when an user logs in, take the submitted password, hash it using the same method (`sha1($password)`), and then compare the password in database with the one you just hashed. This prevents anyone from knowing what the password is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you starting a session in home.php?
You must call `session_start()` at the first line of every php script in which you want to access session variables.

Try adding this in top of home.

```
<?php
session_start();
//Then do your work
```

Then even if `session_start` is called again in head.php or sidebar.php , it will be ignored, as the session was already started.

Comment: I did, but that throws an error on the side bar.
Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\trialphp\head.php:38)

head.php is basically the css and script files and i have imported that on the home.php. it only contains some <head>Some css and some scripts</head>

Comment: The error you're getting means that output is already sent to the browser before starting session. `session_start()` must be called at the very first line, before any output is sent. See updated answer.

Comment: Thanks, it worked.
That means i have to write the session_start() on top of every file that references a session value, right?

Comment: Technically, yes. But a simpler approach will be, make a header file (for eg. `headers.php`). In headers.php, call `session_start()` on the first line. Put all your common functions into that file (if you have functions) , and then include the file on top of every page. That way, if you have to make changes to session, you will not have to edit every page, only the one in `headers.php` .

Comment: Great, i have the head.php file which is included almost on all pages. So i'll use that.
Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @Enq no problem, just remember to start the session before any output is sent (generally that would mean the first line) :)